# Splitting sentence in multiples lines (Bootstrap 4 + Mobile)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a text (sentence) that is fully displayed in the Desktop version. However, I would like to break the sentence into 2-3 lines in Mobile with Bootstrap-4.

e.g., I have the following text (could be h1 or p tag)

> Our large, heavy items and Same-Day Delivery items are delivered by
> our store or one of our delivery partners.

I would like to break for Mobile 3 times, at these specific words/positions...

> ```
> Our large, heavy items and Same-Day Delivery items
> are delivered by our store
> or one of our delivery partners.
> ```

**What choices do I have?**
Once again, this could be in an **h1** or **p** tag, please help with each solution if one does not fit all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just add `spans` and then use the media query to make them load as `block` specifically on mobile devices.

Eg ...

```
<div id="coolDiv">
 <span>Our large, heavy items and Same-Day Delivery items <span/><span>are delivered by our store </span><span>or one of our delivery partners.</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #coolDiv span {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/MohdAbdulMujib/pen/oNYqWgJ)

This will work for all the cases that you mentioned like `<h1>` or `<p>` tags. You can also use specific class to restrict this effect to your use case.

Comment: Tested <span>Worked like a charm</span> Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Playing with text on this fine of a level is pretty hard becuase you don't have access to the browser text engine. My best guess on how you could achieve this would be to have 2  tags and the on you want to show on desktop would be

```
<h1 class="d-sm-none d-xs-none"> Our large, heavy items and Same-Day Delivery items are delivered by our store or one of our delivery partners.</h1>
<h1 class="d-none d-sm-block d-xs-block">Our large, heavy items and Same-Day Delivery items<br>
are delivered by our store<br>
or one of our delivery partners.</h1>
```

Im not sure if these are the correct [classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/) and having 2 h1 tags is bad for SEO however this could be a way you could achieve this. It's kinda janky but it should work.

Comment: Thanks, Purple, I was trying to avoid this specific solution in order to not repeat the tags. If the text change then I need to re-do lots of work. The idea should be to have something inside the text that breaks the lines upon mobile. Now that you mentioned SEO... hmmmm... I am thinking of all the other times I used this -none -block trick. Thanks anyways.. I will study your SEO comment!

Comment: @G305 The SEO problems arise with the 2 <h1> tags which you can avoid using <p> tags

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap each of them in a div and manage it with flexbox, it will automatically push to next line when the width of screen is shorter than the h1 or p context